# Mockito Matchers: matching a Class type in parameter list

Tags: java, generics, mockito, matcher

I am working with Java, Spring's RestTemplate, and Mockito, using Eclipse.  I am trying to mock Spring's rest template, and the last parameter for the method I am mocking is a Class type.  Below is the signature for the function:

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(URI url,
                                  HttpMethod method,
                                  HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
                                  Class<T> responseType)
                       throws RestClientException
```

The initial attempt I made to mock this method is as follows:

```
//given restTemplate returns exception
when(restTemplate.exchange(isA(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.POST), isA(HttpEntity.class), eq(Long.class))).thenThrow(new RestClientException(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
```

However, this line of code produces the following error from eclipse:

```
The method exchange(URI, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<T>) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (URI, HttpMethod, HttpEntity, Class<Long>)
```

Eclipse then suggests I cast the last parameter with a 'Class' cast, but does not seem to work if I cast it to a 'Class', or other type.

I've been looking online for help on this, but seem to stumped on the fact that the parameter requested is a class type.

The answers I've looked at so far have been mainly related to generic collections.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your attempt compiles fine for me.

Comment: Have you checked that you haven't accidentally used a Hamcrest matcher rather than a mockito match, I have been caught out by that before, though usually with any.

Comment: Can you edit to include your Java version?

Comment: It turns out the problem was because the method was parameterized, and needed explicit <type> in front of the method.  I guess it could not imply the type from the matchers.

Answer (score 15):

Figured out.

The method being called was a parameterized method, but could not infer the parameter type from the matcher argument (the last argument was of type Class).

Making the explicit call

```
when(restTemplate.<Long>exchange(isA(URI.class),eq(HttpMethod.POST),isA(HttpEntity.class), eq(Long.class))).thenThrow(new RestClientException(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: I am unable to figure out what is the fix. The stubbing in question and answer is exactly the same. Both have `eq(Long.class)`. What change in the stubbing code fixed the issue?

Comment: @Akshay, it's been quite a while since I wrote this. I think from what was in the comments I put for the original question, I meant to call the exchange function with the parameterized version, such as `when(rest.<Long>exchange(...)).thenThrow(...)`. I'm not sure how that got left out, since the code in the answer definitely doesn't have anything changed in it.  I hope this helps, and I apologize for the confusing post

Comment: @Onema appears to have modified the answer that I posted originally.  Not appreciated, since it basically reverted back to the original form

Comment: Reverted, appologies

Comment: cannot convert from Matcher<Object> to HttpEntity<?>

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet worked for me. For request entity, I used any() instead of isA().

```
PowerMockito
    .when(restTemplate.exchange(
            Matchers.isA(URI.class),
            Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(),
            Matchers.eq(Long.class)))
    .thenThrow(new RestClientException(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
```